# How to split by double or more empty lines? Regex.Stplit adds unwanted strings

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to split this string: `"hello1\r\nhello2\r\n\r\nhello3\r\n\r\n\r\nhello4"`
to: `{"hello1\r\nhello2" , "hello3", "hello4"}`

my code:

```
string text = "hello1\r\nhello2\r\n\r\nhello3\r\n\r\n\r\nhello4"; 
string[] wordsarray = Regex.Split(text, @"(\r\n){2,}");
```

The result is: `{"hello1\r\nhello2" ,"\r\n" , "hello3" ,"\r\n" ,"hello4"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very close. Simply use a non-capturing group:

```
Regex.Split(text, @"(?:\r\n){2,}")
```

`Regex.Split` adds captured groups to the result array as described in "Remarks" section of [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx).

Comment: +1. Remarks secion of [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) have details on the behavior.